# Unable to convert response data of octet-stream to Zip file and download it

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, download, zip

I am trying to download Zip file containing JSON files from AJAX GET Request.

Response Headers format:

```
Connection: keep-alive
content-disposition: attachment;filename=exportedFiles_ 1.6.0_20200731160652.zip
Content-Length: 4496
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2020 10:36:52 GMT
```

Data Preview  in Network Tab:

[image]

AJAX call and success function :

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/download/" ,
      async: false,
      success: function (data,status, xhr) {          
      var filename = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-disposition').split("filename=")[1];;
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"})
       saveAs(blob, filename); 
      }
    });
```

Its saving the Zip file but when I try to open the Zip file it says "**Windows cannot open the folder, The compressed Zip is invalid**".

[image]

Comment: facing similar issue, have you resolved this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

Implement an `Axios` handler for the Received document, the data format `octect-stream`,
data might look weird `PK something JbxfFGvddvbdfbVVH34365436fdkln` as its octet stream format, you might end up creating file with this data might be corrupt, `{responseType: 'blob'}` will make data into readable format,

```
axios.get("URL", {responseType: 'blob'})
     .then((r) => {
         let fileName =  r.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1];
         let blob = new Blob([r.data]);
         window.saveAs(blob, fileName);             
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

you might have tried solution which fails like this,
`window.saveAs(blob, 'file.zip')` will try to save file as zip but will wont work,

```
const downloadFile = (fileData) => {
    axios.get(baseUrl+"/file/download/"+fileData.id)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers['content-type'], encoding:'UTF-8'});
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = 'file.zip';
            link.click();
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
const downloadFile = (fileData) => {
axios.get(baseUrl+"/file/download/"+fileData.id)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        //const binaryString = window.atob(response.data)
        //const bytes = new Uint8Array(response.data)
        //const arrBuff = bytes.map((byte, i) => response.data.charCodeAt(i));
        //var base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(response.data)));
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type:"application/octet-stream"});
        window.saveAs(blob, 'file.zip')
        // const link = document.createElement('a');
        // link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // link.download = 'file.zip';
        // link.click();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    };

    return bytes;
}
```

another short solution is,

```
window.open("URL")
```

will keep opening new tabs unnecessarily and user might have to make `allow popups` for work this code, what if user want to download multiple files at the same time so go with solution first or if not try for other solutions also

Answer (score -1):

Set the response type to arraybuffer:

```
dataType: 'arraybuffer'
```

Comment: what dataType an where to write this and how this will fix this problem?

Comment: In the ajax request: `$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/download/" ,
      async: false,
      success: function (data,status, xhr) {          
      var filename = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-disposition').split("filename=")[1];;
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"})
       saveAs(blob, filename); 
      },
   dataType: 'arraybuffer'
    });` The **dataType** parameter is used to "expect" a custom type back from the server.